# Различие в функции load в версиях 5.1 и 5.2

Tags: lua

Воспроизводя примеры из книги, обнарежил, что пример с ф-цией `load` не отрабатывает:

```
local func = load("print(10)")
```

Так пример для `5.2` а я использовал версию `5.1.5` в результате чего происходила ошибка из-за того, что на вход ожидалась функция, а не строка. Как работала эта функция в `5.1`? Также запускал пример с помощью `luajit` версии `2.1.0-beta3` и он отработал, в связи с чем возник вопрос: какую версию `lua` использует `luajit`? Ведь, например, `table.unpack`, введенная в `5.2` с помощью `luajit` тоже не запускается, а при установке `luajit` устанавливал пакет `libluajit5.1-dev`.

Comment: [какую версию lua использует luajit?] Там в lua должен быть запрос, который возвращает номер версии. Разве его нет?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 где "там" и версии чего? Я уже написал, что версия `luajit` - `2.1.0-beta3`, о версии языка там нет ни строчки

Comment: "там" это в lua и запроса номера версии языка. Но я посмотрел, вроде нет там такого запроса. Увы.

Comment: Справки ради — luajit реализует Lua 5.1 + есть опция при компиляции для нескольких фич 5.2. Версию языка в целом можно узнать из глобальной переменной `_VERSION`.

Answer (score 2):

В 5.1 функция `load` [описана](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-load) как:

```
load (func [, chunkname])
```

т.е. принимает на вход только функцию. И [есть](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-loadstring) функция `loadstring`:

```
loadstring (string [, chunkname])
```

которая принимает строку.

В 5.2 обе эти функции объединили и `load` уже [описана](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-load) как:

```
load (ld [, source [, mode [, env]]])
```

и может принимать как функцию, так и строку.

---

luajit реализует интерфейс lua 5.1 с некоторыми дополнениями.